# Serenity BDD Java 10 use chromedriver as webdriver.driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, serenity-bdd, java-10

I am trying to build an IntelliJ, Java 10/Gradle 4.8 project using the Serenity BDD using the maven command to pull and auto build (using option 3 for Selenium-Junit):

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=serenity
```

The final dependency issue I get is trying to use the Chrome "chromedriver" webdriver as the projects I'm trying to build tests for are projects that are targeted for Chrome web browser. Right now the project defaults to Firefox if no webdriver is listed (Commented out in the serenity.properties file). I have downloaded the chromedriver.exe and placed it in the root directory of the project. I have also changed the default driver to chromedriver in the serenity.properties file:

```
# Define the default driver
webdriver.driver=chromedriver
```

but when I do this and try to run, I get this error:

```
net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException: Unsupported browser type: chromedriver. Did you mean firefox?
```

**What is the exact name to use, or how do I designate Chrome webdriver as the default webdriver?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the chromedriver.exe is placed in the root directory of the project, the serenity.properties file needs to be modified like so:

```
# Define the default driver
webdriver.driver=chrome
webdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe
```